# Haskell: How to carry a value from one function to another

Tags: list, loops, haskell, replace

I have a function 'one' that creates a string of length i,

```
fillWithEmpty :: Int -> String
fillWithEmpty i =
  if i == 0 then "." else "." ++ fillWithEmpty(i - 1)
```

I then want the system to remember the length i so that it can replace a character in the string with 'S' at a position in the string of length i, given a value of a position needed to be replaced, e

```
replaceWithS :: String -> Int -> String
replaceWithS i e=
  if i == e then "S" else "." ++ replaceWithS(i - 1)
```

**Any help would be appreciated. Thanks**

Comment: When does `replaceWithS` get called relative to `fillWIthEmpty` returning, i.e., how long do you need to remember which value was passed to `fillWithEmpty`? An example of how you plan to use both functions would help.

Comment: thanks for the comment, fillWithEmpty would be called first as my string must begin as periods (amount of periods '.' set by a number input). Then when entering a separate number will give the position the letter, in this case S will be inserted to. I havent finished the code yet so i dont have a main function but it would be sort of like function 5 2, which would run fillWithEmpty of length 5 and then replaceWithS at position 2

Comment: your type signature for replaceWithS looks wrong. You are comparing i and e but one is an integer and one is a String. Your recursive call to replaceWithS has one one parameter. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explicit recursion to enumerate over the list. Each time you make a call where you *decrement* the index, and if the index is `0` you use an `S` instead of the value of the given string, so:

```
replaceWithS :: String -> Int -> String
replaceWithS "" _ = ""
replaceWithS (_:xs) 0 = … : …
replaceWithS (x:xs) i = … : replaceWithS … …
```

Here `x` is thus the head of the string (its first character), and `xs` is a list with the remaining characters. You here still need to fill in the `…` parts.